# get_tree().get_nodes_in_group() returning deleted nodes

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm making a battle scene that has a controller that counts the amount of enemies on the scene. When that count reaches 0 it should send you back to the previous scene.
But my `get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Enemy")` is always returning the same number regardless of enemies killed
Here is the code for my Controller

```
extends Node2D

var nodes
var enemy_count = 0
    

        
func _physics_process(delta):
    enemy_count = 0
    nodes = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Enemy")
    for node in nodes:
        enemy_count += 1
    print(enemy_count)
    if enemy_count <= 0:
        get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://scenes/samples/top_down_sample.tscn")
```

Here is the code of my enemy when it dies:

```
func _on_hit_box_on_killed():
    get_parent().remove_child(self)
    self.queue_free()
```

It seems that even with queue_free, the enemy is not trully deleted from the tree?

I've tried to find something online that could help, even changing `queue_free()` to `free()`, but then it warns me the node is blocked and can't be deleted.

Comment: I made a small project with your code snippets. It works as intended. I made it so they are removed on click. They get freed and the enemy_count goes down.

Did you look into your scene tree while debugging? Are the nodes actually getting removed from the scene?
Does your enemy script has any parts which could lead into a state, that the node can't be freed?

Comment: Adding to my comment: get_parent().remove_child(self) is enough to remove it from nodes in group. Meaning the queue_free part is for your problem not even relevant.

So my take is, that your _on_hit_box_on_killed is not called at all? Did you try to put a print there to see if it is called?

Comment: The code is being called since the enemies disappear from the screen when I play the game.  So I am thinking now that perhaps it might be that the animated_sprite is getting deleted alone? Maybe the enemy itself is still there. 
I'll try adding another get_parent() in there and see what happens

Comment: Well if that does not work, consider putting the important parts (all relevant code for the groups and the tree structure) here. Right now I also can just guess blindly .) As you said, it could ve important where your script is in the tree and how your enemy node is nested

Comment: It worked. It wasn't deleting the right element!